# get previous value of pandas datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with datetime index

```
Date
2013-02-22 00:00:00+00:00    0.280001
2013-02-25 00:00:00+00:00    0.109999
2013-02-26 00:00:00+00:00   -0.150000
2013-02-27 00:00:00+00:00    0.130001
2013-02-28 00:00:00+00:00    0.139999
Name: MOM12
```

and want to evaluate the previous three values of the given datetime index.

```
date = "2013-02-27 00:00:00+00:00"
df.ix[date]
```

I searched for this but since my index is a date I can't do

```
df.ix[int-1]
```

Comment: Do you have an index for each day or are there some skipped days?

Comment: There are some skipped days, weekends and holidays for example.

Comment: This question could help you: [slice pandas timeseries on date +/- 2 business days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092339/slice-pandas-timeseries-on-date-2-business-days)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, first grab the integer location of the index key via `get_loc`:

```
In [15]: t = pd.Timestamp("2013-02-27 00:00:00+00:00")

In [16]: df1.index.get_loc(t)
Out[16]: 3
```

And then you can use `iloc` (to get the integer location, or slice by integer location):

```
In [17]: loc = df1.index.get_loc(t)

In [18]: df.iloc[loc - 1]
Out[18]: 
Date    2013-02-26 00:00:00
                      -0.15
Name: 2, Dtype: object

In [19]: df1.iloc[slice(max(0, loc-3), min(loc, len(df)))]
        # the min and max feel slightly hacky (!) but needed incase it's within top or bottom 3
Out[19]:                         
Date                    
2013-02-22  0.280001
2013-02-25  0.109999
2013-02-26 -0.150000
```

See the [indexing section of the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position).

---

*I'm not quite sure how you set up your DataFrame, but that doesn't look like a Datetime Index to me.* Here's how I got the DataFrame (with Timestamp index):

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+', header=None, parse_dates=[0], names=['Date', None])

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
                 Date          
0 2013-02-22 00:00:00  0.280001
1 2013-02-25 00:00:00  0.109999
2 2013-02-26 00:00:00 -0.150000
3 2013-02-27 00:00:00  0.130001
4 2013-02-28 00:00:00  0.139999

In [13]: df1 = df.set_index('Date')

In [14]: df1
Out[14]:                
Date                
2013-02-22  0.280001
2013-02-25  0.109999
2013-02-26 -0.150000
2013-02-27  0.130001
2013-02-28  0.139999
```

Comment: support for irow has been deprecated: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.irow.html , iloc[...]  should be used instead

Comment: @user2413548 thanks, I need to write a script to go through all these answers!

Answer (score 3):

Could you just do `df.shift().loc[date]`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and thanks to Andy Hayden's solution, I got it working for iterating over rows of a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex. So I threw it in a small function. It can be used to get previous or future values. If the index doesn't go out of bounds.

```
def get_row(df, row, n = 0, value = None):
    loc = df.index.get_loc(row[0])
    if value == None:
        return df.iloc[loc + n]
    else:
        return df.iloc[loc + n][value]
```

So while iterating over the rows, you can call this function.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    # Get past value of a whole row
    get_row(df, row, -1)
    # Get past value of a certain column of a row
    get_row(df, row, -1, "column_name")
    # Get future value of a certain column of a row
    get_row(df, row, 1, "column_name")

    # Can be used to get the current row but this is slower than the following function
    # Slower
    get_row(df, row, 0, "column_name")
    # Faster
    row[data.columns.get_loc("column_name") + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

use shift to get the previous row values

```
data=[('2013-02-22 00:00:00+00:00',    0.280001)
,('2013-02-25 00:00:00+00:00',    0.109999)
,('2013-02-26 00:00:00+00:00',   -0.150000)
,('2013-02-27 00:00:00+00:00',    0.130001)
,('2013-02-28 00:00:00+00:00',    0.139999)]
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['date','value'])
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['p_value']=df.value.shift(1)
df['pp_value']=df.value.shift(2)
df['ppp_value']=df.value.shift(3)
print(df)
```

output

```
         date                    value   p_value  pp_value  ppp_value
 0 2013-02-22 00:00:00+00:00  0.280001       NaN       NaN        NaN
 1 2013-02-25 00:00:00+00:00  0.109999  0.280001       NaN        NaN
 2 2013-02-26 00:00:00+00:00 -0.150000  0.109999  0.280001        NaN
 3 2013-02-27 00:00:00+00:00  0.130001 -0.150000  0.109999   0.280001
 4 2013-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  0.139999  0.130001 -0.150000   0.109999
```