# Can a DataFrame be "reverse indexed"?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a builtin function to "reverse index" a pandas data frame? For example, if the data frame represents time series data, and we iterate through the time series data, is there a builtin function to access the date for a given value?

Example:

```
# Let series be a pandas data frame with a column header and row labels as dates. 
for i in series:
    # do stuff
    if something:
        get date for this i
```

Or is it necessary to just go through the data in a different fashion?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162605/get-previous-value-of-pandas-datetime-index) could help you.

Comment: Have a look at the timing comparisons below.  Iteration is much faster than comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
series[series==i].index
```

If there can be multiple dates for the same value, you could do `series[series==i].index.tolist()`

Comment: This method is very inefficient for the OP's stated purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate over the series and then access the index at the same location:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=pd.date_range('2015-1-1', periods=4))

for i, val in enumerate(df['val']):
    print((df.index[i], val))

(Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00', offset='D'), 1)
(Timestamp('2015-01-02 00:00:00', offset='D'), 2)
(Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00', offset='D'), 3)
(Timestamp('2015-01-04 00:00:00', offset='D'), 4)
```

You can also use `iteritems`, as done here with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [(i, j) for i, j in df.val.iteritems()]
[(Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00', offset='D'), 1),
 (Timestamp('2015-01-02 00:00:00', offset='D'), 2),
 (Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00', offset='D'), 3),
 (Timestamp('2015-01-04 00:00:00', offset='D'), 4)]
```

Here are some timing comparisons using a dataframe with 1000 random values.

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.randn(1000)}, 
                  index=pd.date_range('2015-1-1', periods=1000))

%timeit [(i, j) for i, j in df.val.iteritems()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 692 µs per loop

%timeit [(df.index[i], val) for i, val in enumerate(df['val'])]
10 loops, best of 3: 18.9 ms per loop

%timeit [df[df == val] for val in df['val']]
1 loops, best of 3: 901 ms per loop
```