# How to create a data frame column based on a formula which starts with an initial variable value of zero

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

*I'm new with Python but trying my best to teach myself as I go along so I apologize if the question is poorly written*

I have the following `DataFrame` `df` with a column `Z30` of `ZScore` values:

| Z30 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1.2 |
| 0.85 |
| 0.50 |
| -0.50 |
| -1.20 |
| -1.85 |
| 0.75 |
| 1.5 |
| 2 |

I like to create a new column next to it called `Z30DELTA` with some sort of formula that can do the following:

Initialize `zdelta` variable to `0` , then:

```
if Z30[i] > 1 or if Z30[i] < -1 => zdelta[i] = zdelta.shift(1)[i] + Z30[i]
else zdelta[i] = zdelta.shift(1)[i]
```

End result would be:

| Z30 | Z30DELTA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1.2 | 1.2 |
| 0.85 | 1.2 |
| 0.50 | 1.2 |
| -0.50 | 0.70 |
| -1.20 | -0.50 |
| -1.85 | -2.35 |
| 0.75 | -2.35 |
| 1.5 | -0.85 |
| 2 | 1.15 |

I researched and thought perhaps I could use `numpy` where function as follows:

```
z30delta = np.where((total_df['Z30'] > 1) | (total_df['Z30'] < -1), xxxx, yyyy)
df["Z30DELTA"] = z30delta
```

but I can't figure out how to get `xxxx` and `yyyy` to do what I want.

How to get `xxxx` to be equal to the previous row value of `Z30DELTA + total_df['Z30']`
How to get `yyyy` to be equal to the previous row value of `Z30DELTA`

Comment: Please provide your data as formated code, not as running text. You can use triple backticks `\``` for code chunks or single backticks \` for inline code

Answer (score 0):

For the row where Z30 is -0.5, which doesn't satisfy your if condition, shouldn't the previous value be copied as it is in zdelta?

If yes, here is one way you can approach this problem:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

Z30 = [1,1.2,0.85,0.50,-0.50,-1.20,-1.85,0.75,1.5,2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Z30': Z30})
df = df.set_index(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=10))
df['Z30DELTA'] = 0


def condition(df,i):
    if  df.loc[i, 'Z30'] > 1 or  df.loc[i, 'Z30'] < -1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

for i, values in df.iterrows():
    loc = df.index.get_loc(i)
    print(loc)
    df.loc[i, 'Z30DELTA'] = df['Z30DELTA'].iloc[loc-1]  + df.loc[i, 'Z30']* condition(df,i)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution when applied in a separate document works. However I am having a difficult time incorporating it in my dataframe. Besides changing df to my dataframe's name, what else should I modify? I think it has to do with the range function since my total_df.index is not numerical but datetime (dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=5000, freq=None)

Comment: Why is this not working? @AzulCou


total_df['Z30DELTA'] = 0
    def condition(total_df, i):
        if total_df.loc[i, 'Z30'] > 1 or total_df.loc[i, 'Z30'] < -1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    for i in total_df.index:
        total_df.loc[i, 'Z30DELTA'] = total_df.loc[i - 1, 'Z30DELTA'] + total_df.loc[i, 'Z30'] * condition(total_df, i)

Comment: TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Comment: The issue lies on this **total_df.loc[i - 1,'Z30DELTA']** since my df has a datetime index. I tried total_df['Z30DELTA'].shift(1) but that doesn't work either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can try the edited solution. Reference link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162605/get-previous-value-of-pandas-datetime-index